# Ubuntu 14.04.1 is consuming 7.8 gigs of 8 gigs ram?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, memory-leak, 14.04

Actually had to create a new account due to openid 2.0 obsolete....I havent been on Askubuntu in quite awhile but tonight I was doing some work on a website when noticing my computer for once was acting sluggish>??

I checked system monitor and noticed 7.8 gigs of ram out of 8 GIGS WAS BEING USED....IS THERE A MEMORY LEAK going on? Im also running an MSI r7 250x graphics card on an intel quad core system...At the time of noticing this issue all I had opened was Filezilla and a folder.......Whats going on? 8 gigs is way too much for an OS to need sitting at idle

Comment: If you can use System Monitor, it can show which process is using how much memory. Sort by memory, and you'll know who's eating into it.

Comment: Already checked system monitor ....nothing is sticking out everything seems normal....terminal shows 7.8 gigs used of 7.9. And I'm dumping 308 megs of page cache..that's very unusual for me...this is the first time I've noticed this..I know linux takes free memory and holds it so things work faster but its the first time its taken all my memory

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the great answer in SE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802481/how-to-see-top-processes-by-actual-memory-usage):

> First, repeat this mantra for a little while: "unused memory is wasted
>   memory". The Linux kernel keeps around huge amounts of file metadata
>   and files that were requested, until something that looks more
>   important pushes that data out. It's why you can run:
>
> ```
> find /home -type f -name '*.mp3'
> find /home -type f -name '*.aac'
> ```
>
> and have the second find instance run at ridiculous speed.
>
> Linux only leaves a little bit of memory 'free' to handle spikes in
>   memory usage without too much effort.

Now you have many tools to list the process such the GUI app `system monitor` or CLI tools such as `top` , `htop` etc....

You could just fire up top and press M to sort processes by memory usage.

Comment: Related: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/